Sinusoidally-varying uniform electric field in a conductive medium: how to derive the decay of the electric field with distance in the medium
I am using CST Studio Suite to model a sinusoidally-varying uniform electric field through a long conductive circular wire. The excitation is through a current port, as shown below, and here are the wire's simulation parameters:

$I=100\pi$ A
Wire has a radius of $1$ m and a length of $50$ m
The current density is $J=100$ A/$m^2$:
The conductivity is $1$ mS/m
The permitivitty and permeability are that of free space


The expected results are to see a UNIFORM electric field down the wire and a magnetic field around the wire. As shown below, this is the case (100 Hz):
Magnetic Field:

Electric Field:

However,:

There is also an electric field outside of the wire (likely due to Faraday's Law on the circular magnetic field)
At higher frequencies (10,000 Hz ) the electric field intensity decreases along the cable, as shown below:


To fully understand the mathematical reason for this simulation result, I am trying (and struggling) to:

Derive the equation for the electric field outside of the wire, as I feel this has a contribution to the skin effect.
Derive the exact expression for the skin effect (decay) shown.

Here is some of the work I have done so far:
$
\oint \mathbf{H} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = \int \left( \mathbf{J} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d\mathbf{s}
$
$
\mathbf{H} = \hat{\phi} \left( \mathbf{J} + \frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\frac{\partial \mathbf{J}}{\partial t} \right)\frac{ \int  d\mathbf{s}}{\oint dl} 
$
$
\mathbf{I} = \mathbf{J} + \frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\frac{\partial \mathbf{J}}{\partial t}
$
$r$ is the radius of the magnetic field and $a$ is the radius of the conductor:
$
\mathbf{H} = 
   \hat{\phi}\mathbf{I} \begin{cases} 
      \frac{r}{2} & r\leq a \\
      \frac{a^2}{2r} & r>a
   \end{cases}
$
$
\tilde{\mathbf{I}} = \tilde{\mathbf{J}} + j\omega\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\tilde{\mathbf{J}}
$
$
\tilde{\mathbf{H}} = 
   \hat{\phi}\mathbf{\tilde{I}} \begin{cases} 
      \frac{r}{2} & r\leq a \\
      \frac{a^2}{2r} & r>a
   \end{cases}
$
$
\nabla \times \tilde{\mathbf{E}} =
-\frac{\partial \tilde{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} =
   -j\omega\mu\hat{\phi}\mathbf{\tilde{I}}
   \begin{cases} 
      \frac{r}{2} & r\leq a \\
      \frac{a^2}{2r} & r>a
   \end{cases}
$
IF my math is correct, I don't know what to do from here. All help is appreciated.
EDIT:
I was advised to see the skin effect, and found that the formula for skin effect was (when ignoring phase changes):
$J=J_Se^{-d/\delta}$
Where:
$\delta=\sqrt{\frac{2\rho}{\omega\mu}\left(\sqrt{1+(\rho\omega\varepsilon)^2}+\rho\omega\varepsilon\right)}$
When I plot the expected current density on desmos (10,000 Hz):

This is different to the simulation result (below), indicating that this is not the reason for the problem.


your question is really unclear, please, add a drawing that corresponds to the text and describe in detail the setup of your problem.

@hyportnex Hope this is better! I am new to electromagnetics and have been studying it from an engineering perspective, so am struggling to explain it to physicists. Thank you for your patience.

because $\nabla \times \mathbf H= (\sigma + \mathfrak j \omega)\mathbf E$ the effective conductivity is frequency dependent. A practical example is RF communications in sea water, it is almost impossible beyond a few meters and above a few kHz because of this problem.

@MrChickenNuggetBadman The concept you're talking about is the skin effect.

@VincentThacker I am not sure about this as the question is a bit obscure but the title says "conductive medium" in which case the skin effect is only one and thus, potentially, a very small part of the problem, hence my comment above.

Thank you very much for all your help despite my obscurity; please bear with me. What I know of the skin effect is when you have an electromagnetic wave, so that there is propagation perpendicular to both the electric field and magnetic field. In this case, the "propagation" is parallel to the electric field, so I am struggling to derive this decay.

I'm struggling to understand the boundary conditions of your problem. What is set up at the start? The E-field? The current density?

Please don't use rainbow plots, they mask the information you're trying to show (so as to effectively provide no information). There are better options available.

@MrChickenNuggetBadman The skin effect applies to alternating current in wires. The current is parallel to the electric field as $\mathbf{J}=\sigma\mathbf{E}$. I'm fairly certain it is the effect you're experiencing. The equations are on the Wikipedia page I linked in my previous comment.

@KyleKanos interesting! what is the alternative plot colour for beginners then? I know each has its use case, but which is typically the best as a beginner to simulation software?

@VincentThacker thank you very much for that. It appears, however, that this was not the issue (see edited question)

@MrChickenNuggetBadman the options you have depends on what you're tying to show. Typically, if you are trying to show some bimodal grouping, you want 2 colors with white between. If it's a 'strength' of some sort, use a light to dark (or inverse) coloring. If it's a categorization, use several colors.
